# java CRUD application stuck on "Update"!

Tags: java, database, spring, crud

I am working on CRUD application using Java Spring, and JDBC. I've watched tutorials but I stuck at "U" letter of the crUd :).
I've done some things but I would appreciate if you would help me.

Here are things that I've done:

TournamentDAO:

```
public void edit(Tournament tournament){
    String sql = "update TOURNAMENT.TOURNAMENT set name = ? , location = ? , date = ? , where id = ?";

    m_jdbcTemplate.update(sql, 
              new Object[]{ 
              tournament.getName(),
              tournament.getLocation(),
              tournament.getDate(), 
              Long.toString(tournament.getId())
    });
}
```

Controller "EditTournament":

```
@Controller
public class EditTournament {

    @Autowired
    private TournamentService turnirSer;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editTournament", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView edit(@RequestParam("id") Integer id) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("editTournament");
        Tournament Tournament = turnirSer.getById(id);
        mav.addObject("editTournament", tournament);
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editTournament", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String update(Model model, @Valid Tournament tournament,
            BindingResult bindingResult,
            @ModelAttribute("tournamentList") ArrayList<Tournament> TournamentList) {
        if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            turnirSer.editTournament(tournament);
            tournamentList.add(tournament);         
        }
        return "editTournament";
    }

}
```

Now just to say I KNOW THIS IS TOTALLY A MESS that's why I need your help!

In this line:

```
Tournament Tournament = turnirSer.getById(id);
```

I don't have method `getById(id)`, I took it form tutorial which is based on Hibernate which I don't use and I have no idea how to create one!

Can someone please explain me what is wrong and how to write this code so that my update works.

PS. create,read and delete is working fine. To post this question here was my last option, I've done what I could.

Comment: It's better that you show stack trace of exception.

Answer (score 4):

You have extra

```
 ,
```

before `where` in query

```
date = ? , where id = ?";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have one more method in your `TournamentDAO` (or in its super class if you want to implement it bit generic) with name `getById(String id)`, The implementation goes something like

```
public Tournament getById(String id){
    String sql = "select name, location, date from TOURNAMENT.TOURNAMENT where id = :id";
    List<Map<String, String>> results = m_jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, new HashMap<String, String>(){{put("id", id)}});
    //as id would be the primary key, at max you may one record (one entry in the list).
    Map<String, Object> result = results.get(0); //add a check for no results
        Tournament t = new Tournament();
        t.setName(result.get("name"));
        //set all your properties as mentioned above
    return t;
    }
```

There are other options that `jdbctemplate` provides like `RowMaper` and `RowCallbackHandler` which will help you automate hardcoding the property names and all.

Refer [this link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/SpringJDBC/article.html) for a basic example.